# Open a program in finder with only keyboard

Tags: macos, finder

If I navigate to a program in my Applications folder in Finder and press enter the program offers to be renamed. Only a double-click with the mouse opens the app.

How can I open it with only the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to open apps from the keyboard.

Other way is to use Spotlight <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and type the app name, then hit enter.